# error: no matching function for call to 'QTimer::singleShot'

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem with a class I am trying to implement. Basically, I want to start a singleshot timer when the class gets constructed and connect it to one of the classes slots. At the moment my constructor looks like this:

```
myclass::myclass(int time)
{
    QTimer::singleShot(time, this, SLOT(myslot()));
}
```

And produces the error in the title. I already found out that myclass has to be a Q_OBJECT but this didn't fix the error. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: What's the full content of error message?

Comment: Sorry, dont have the code on this machine. Run into the problem yesterday and thought I ask now if someone has an idea how to fix it so I can continue working when I get home. I will provide more information this evening if we can't find an solution now.

Comment: I think that Zaiborg's answer below should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QGraphicsItem doesnt't inherits QObject, then you should change myclass

```
// thanks to WoJo for pointing out the right inheritance order
class myclass : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem
//class myclass : public QGraphicsItem, public QObject
{ Q_OBJECT
...
public slots:
  void myslot();

}
```

In my experience you'll need to *delete* the build directory to force a clean rebuild after that.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising.

Comment: it should solve the problem; had forgotten that the Q...Item's are not derived from QObject

Comment: If you are trying to animate your graphics, take a look at [animation framework](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtanimationframework/animation.html). It's powerful and high-level.

Comment: you have to derived from QObject first! `class myclass : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem` http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html#multiple-inheritance-requires-qobject-to-be-first

Comment: and you can derive from only one QObject based class. AFAIK QGraphicsItem is not, so it should be fine

Answer (score 1):

Did your classe inherit of QObject, QWidget or other widget ?
Did  you include `<QTimer>` in your program ?

Comment: Yes, it is included in the program. The class inherits from QGraphicsItem, is that the error?

Comment: No, Zaiborg answer to you, I don't see the SLOT(myslot) sorry.
Whe you use a signal or slot you always need to put () with the name, and type parameter if need (like myslot(int) or myslot() for example).

Comment: I think you are right. Looks like QGraphicsItem doesn't inherit from QObject and can't use the slot/signal functionality. I will try if it works if my class inherits from both QObject and QGraphicsItem and let you know.

Comment: Yes i'm not sure at 100% for QGraphicsItem but if you try with QObject or other this is will work.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
QTimer::singleShot(time, this, SLOT(myslot))); // this should give you a syntax error as well
```

to

```
QTimer::singleShot(time, this, SLOT(myslot()));
```

but be aware; it can cause much trouble when invoking its own method after some time.
it may come to a race codition when you call some function of that class object and the timer ends and directly calls `myslot()`.

Comment: uh, that was only a typo, sorry. It is already ...SLOT(myslot()));

Comment: By the way, thanks for the advice with the race condition, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

As many of the answers already given have pointed out, QGraphicsItem does not inherit from QObject, which is used for signals and slots.

However, rather than using multiple inheritance with QGraphicsItem and QObject, you could simply derive from the Qt class **QGraphicsObject**, which is designed to provide a GraphicsItem that requires signals and slots and is itself derived from QGraphicsItem. It also then gives you the QTimer functionality you mention in your question.