# How to make time gap or delay between two parts of code meanwhile program continue? C++

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have the following code:

```
if(collision == 1)
{
    painter->setBrush(QColor(Qt::red));
    painter->setPen(QColor(Qt::black));
    painter->drawEllipse(QPoint(boundingRect().x() + (boundingRect().width() / 1.7),
                             boundingRect().y() + (boundingRect().width() / 2.1)),
                             boundingRect().width() / 5,
                             boundingRect().height() / 10);

    /*THERE SHOUD BE THE TIME GAP AND THEN DO*/
    collision = 0;
}
```

I want to use this code to paint red ellipse, but only for few seconds (after collision). 
Therefore I have to make time gap or delay between two parts of this code.
The problem here is that I do not know how to do it.

I tried sleep() or wait() or:

```
QTime dieTime= QTime::currentTime().addSecs(1);
while( QTime::currentTime() < dieTime )
QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100);
```

**but these STOP or PAUSE whole PROGRAM** I just want to delay execution of "collision = 0"
Any ideas?

Comment: look into [threading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266168/simple-example-of-threading-in-c)

Comment: If you just want a piece of code to run after a certain amount of time has passed, [look into QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtimer.html).  For more complex concurrency, see [Qt's Threading Model](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/examples-threadandconcurrent.html) *(though note that C++11 now has threads as part of the standard, so depending on your needs it may be better to start learning that way vs. the Qt way)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sleep()` or `wait()` stop all your GUI thread, so it freezes. Try to use `singleShot` from `QTimer`. For example:

```
QTimer::singleShot(4000,this,SLOT(mySlot()));
```

In `mySlot` you can do all needed stuff. In this case `singleShot` will not freeze your GUI. For example set collision to zero and call update, it will call `paintEvent` and in this `paintEvent` with zero collision your ellipse will not be drawn again.

Comment: `QTimer::singleShot(4000,this,SLOT(collisionSet()));
void OtesanekItem::collisionSet()
{
    collision = 0;
}`
This code gives me error: no matching function for call to 'QTimer::singleShot(int, OtesanekItem* const, const char*)'

Comment: @OndřejKrál See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212909/error-no-matching-function-for-call-to-qtimersingleshot there are solutions for QGraphicsItem subclass or just including QTimer